# Inhabilitar Botones Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, botón

Buenas necesito  inhabilitar los botones de mi aplicación de una radio  hasta que este se ejecute el stream de música, y luego que  funcionen con normalidad dado que si toco algún botón antes de iniciar el stream se cierra.Intente con un if y `boton.setEnabled` pero luego los botones no funcionan inclusive después de iniciar el la radio . Desde ya muchas gracias.

Codigo java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ImageButton btnPlay;
int a;

ImageButton btnRec;
ImageButton btnStp;
ImageButton btnSal;
Button btnMul;
Button btnRa;
Button btnNos;

MediaPlayer mediaplayer;
String stream="http://streams.calmradio.com/api/43/128/stream/;";
boolean prepared,started=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    btnRec = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reconectar);
    btnStp = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.parar);
    btnSal = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.salir);
    btnMul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.multimedia);
    btnRa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.radio);
    btnNos = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nosotros);

    final Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Esperando respúesta del Servidor...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.show();

    mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaplayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    new PlayerTask().execute(stream);



  //botones Radio
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (started){
                started=false;
                mediaplayer.pause();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pausa",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else{
                started=true;
                mediaplayer.start();
                btnPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
                Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    });

    btnStp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    });
    btnRec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.stop();
            Intent Recargar =getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(Recargar );
        }
    });

    //Botones Navegacion
    btnSal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mediaplayer.release();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    btnNos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Nosotros=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Nosotros.class);
            startActivity(Nosotros);
            mediaplayer.stop();

        }
    });

    btnMul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent Multimedia=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Multimedia.class);
            startActivity(Multimedia);
            mediaplayer.stop();
        }
    });



}

 class PlayerTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{


    protected Boolean doInBackground(String...String){
        try{
            mediaplayer.setDataSource(String[0]);
            mediaplayer.prepare();
            prepared=true;
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){

        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        mediaplayer.start();

    }

    private class BecomingNoisyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if(AudioManager.ACTION_AUDIO_BECOMING_NOISY.equals(intent.getAction()));
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desde el layout puedes iniciar los botones como desactivados.

```
android:clickable="false"
```

Y una vez tengas la respuesta de tu tarea asíncrona, podrás actualizar el poniendolo en enabled.

```
yourButton.setEnabled(true);
```

No olvides que cuando actualizas la interfaz desde otro hilo deberás decirle a tu programa que lo haga en el hilo principal, ya que puede llevar a crashes en ejecución.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Answer (score 0):

Podés iniciar la aplicación con los controles deshabilitados.
Y, a falta de un evento que te indique cuando volver a habilitarlos, podes diferir la ejecución de un Runnable para que los habilite un par de segundos más tarde.

```
boton.setEnabled(false);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boton.setEnabled(true);
    }
},2000);
```